# Ant tasks, errors

Tags: ant

We're using QVCS here. I was trying to automate the check in and checkout tasks. Referring to the QVCS website: http://qvcs.cbmc.co.uk:9080/docs/qvcsanttask.html

I have the below script:

```
<taskdef name="qvcs"
        classpath="${classpath};${basedir}/ant.jar;${basedir}/gui_out.jar"
        classname="com.qumasoft.qvcslib.QVCSAntTask"/>
<!-- =================================================================== -->
  <!-- Get by label for all project files                                  -->
  <!-- =================================================================== -->
  <target name="GetByLabel"
          depends="getPassword,getLabel,getInstallDir,getServerName"
          description="Get by label from the Production Server.">
      <qvcs userDirectory="${qvcs.installDir}"
            serverName="${qvcs.serverName}"
            userName="Your QVCS-Enterprise Username"
            password="${qvcs.password}"
            projectName="name of the project you want to work on"
            viewName="name of the view you want to work on"
            appendedPath=""
            operation="get"
            workfileLocation="the local workfile directory where results will go."
            overWriteFlag="true"
            label="${qvcs.label}">
      </qvcs>

  </target>
```

I am not very familiar with ANT. I put this file in the ANT directory and the gui_out.jar in same place. But I get this error:
BUILD FAILED

```
\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\build.xml:3: Unexpected element "{}taskdef" {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}taskdef
```

Any help on this would be great, thank you.

Comment: I hope you realize that in `viewName="name of the view you want to work on"` you need to replace the string `name of the view you want to work on` with the actual name of the view you want to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use Ant to automate checkouts and checkins. You then have to make sure everyone has Ant installed, has the `gui_out.jar`, and whatever else they need. As pointed out before, your script needs `<project>` and `</project>` at the top and bottom, but your script still has issues:

- You don't have the following targets defined.

  - getPassword
  - getLabel
  - getInstallDir
  - getServerName

  You're checkout *target* depends upon these other targets being defined, and you don't have them defined.
- Your `<qvcs/>` target has literal strings which are probably something that users should be setting on their own. I'm pretty certain `Your QVCS-Enterprise Username` isn't a valid user name in your system. These have to be turned into properties, and have someway for the user to set them -- either by a properties file, or by asking for input.
- There's a chicken and egg dilemma in putting checkout/checkin information in your build file (which is what Ant is). When you do a checkout, what happens if there's a change in the build script? How does the checkout handle that?

Are you using Ant for your builds, and just want to add in the ability to check in and checkout? Or are you using Ant to do the automation for checking in and out?

Ant isn't a programming scripting language. It's a build dependency matrix language. It tries to figure out what it needs to do a build and in what order. You don't give Ant step-by-step directions to do a build. You tell Ant what target to run, and what that target depends upon. Ant will build a dependency matrix and then figure out what goes first and what goes next. Controlling the order of operations can be very difficult.

If you want to automate, use programming tools. On a PC, use batch scripts or better yet PowerShell. On Unix, use Shell scripting or Perl or Python. Better still, make sure your developers use an IDE for development, and let that IDE take care of your qvcs checkouts and check ins. It's hard to tell what IDE you can use. It depends upon your programming environment.

By the way, things don't look good for [qvcs support](https://qumahobby.wordpress.com/2014/10/26/qumasoft-com-is-no-more/), you may want to move to a more broadly supported tool. The sooner the better.

Comment: Thx David, so I got the ANT script going. And as you were saying, I am actually trying to automate. We're using Ultraedit, no IDE. I thought I could not let Java take over once my ANT script is working. But everyone will have to have ANT installed? I tried to do this through Java but I was not successful.

Comment: If you're not using Ant for builds, and you're using PCs, you may want to look into doing a [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) script. PowerShell is on all Windows since XP came out, but it's highly underutilized. It's a mixture of VIsualBasic and batch shell. It's object oriented and isn't all that difficult to learn. If you want to automate, and your a Windows shop, PowerShell might be something to look into.

Comment: How can powershell set up the fields like ant is doing? QVCS doesn't have interface to powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Ant buildfiles should start with a `project` element:

```
<project default="default_target" name="Example project">
    ...
</project>
```

Inside the `project` element you would declare targets, taskdefs, etc.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#buildfile.

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through the QVCS site, and now realize there's no command line client!

> Since a Java-based command line tool could be very slow because it would require the loading of the JVM for each separate version control operation, we have chosen to supply command line like behavior for the QVCS-Enterprise product via a custom ant task.

Yeah, Ant would be way faster -- except that Ant too has to load the JVM each version control operation!

This is going to be very complicated...

- The `build.xml` has to be accessible for the user to use it. It looks like you have to *lock* individual files for editing which means you probably won't be in the directory with the `build.xml` in it.
- You need a way to set parameters. Sitting there and asking for all of the parameters for each command will simply take too much work.

Each command would look something like this:

```
$ ant -f %BUILD_DIR%/build.xml -Duser=david -Dpassword=swordfish -Dview=default -DWorkfilelocation=... lock
```

You need the `-f` parameter to point to the location of the build.xml file. You need the various `-D` parameters to fill in all the information you must supply to the command line client each and every time.

I imagine that this *command line client* may end up consisting of several pieces:

- A batch script for each and every command you want to execute.
- A `build.xml` file in a known location that the batch scripts would execute.
- A way of setting up parameters.
- A mechanism to store the basic information about your *working copy* status: What's the name of the view? What user did the checkout? What's the user's password? Etc, etc, etc. Maybe in a directory like SVN (`.svn`) or Git (`.git`) does, so you can have multiple checkouts.

Is it possible? Probably. Is it worth it? Probably not. In the end, you're probably better off writing it in pure Java with a batch script to invoke your Java program. Again, the way `git` or `svn` do something like that:

```
C:> qvcs checkout -user david -password swordfish view ...
```

One less thing you need to install.

I would highly recommend abandonment of qvcs. The clock is ticking. Jim Vorbis has announced qvsc's abandonment. The website is now some health supplement sales site. Mr. Vorbis has not released the source code and doesn't offer the server piece.

I would triage the information you need from qvcs. Maybe fetch the last so many iterations, and check those into Git or Subversion. Then, use what you can from qvcs strictly for history that you can't get from the new system. Even Jim Vorbis doesn't have a better suggestion:

> The simplest approach is to check in all your version controlled files into the new tool, and use QVCS for old history. All other approaches are a lot more work, and may not produce results reliable enough to be useful.

Some day, your qvcs repository will die. Maybe a new version of Windows will come out where qvcs doesn't work. Maybe the server software will go down, and you can't get it up and running once more. If you don't move, you'll lose everything.

You're best bet is to use your resources to move out of QVCS.